# Name TestSuite with Nose

Tags: python, nose

I'm using nose to run tests programatically and producing xunit xml.  I've noticed in the xml, the testsuite's name attribute is always nosetests.  I'd like to change this value to the directory name containing my tests, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.

So in the snippet below, I'd like `name="nosetests"` to read `name="sample_test"`

```
....
<testsuite name="nosetests" tests="3" errors="1" failures="1" skip="0">
<testcase classname="app.sample_test.passing" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the test suite name, you may use the input parameter

```
--xunit-testsuite-name=YOURTESTSUITENAME
```

http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html#cmdoption-xunit-testsuite-name